# How to deduplicate the code getting parameters and checking nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, reflection, metaprogramming

```
token = params[:token]
email = params[:email]
phone_number = params[:phone_number]
iso_code = params[:iso_code]

if token.nil? or email.nil? or phone_number.nil? or iso_code.nil?
  raise InvalidParameterException
end

token.strip!
email.strip!
phone_number.strip!
iso_code.strip!

#use the variables
```

There are many this code in my rails project.
How do you generalization this pattern in Ruby on Rails?
Is it possible with reflection and meta programming?

Comment: There needs a bit more clarity here. Are you checking for absence of a value within the hash, or checking whether the value is actually `nil`?

Comment: Good point, I'm checking the absence of a variable. I'll update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unless [:token, :email, :phone_number, :iso_code].-(params.keys).empty?
  raise InvalidParameterException
end
params.each{|_, v| v.strip!}
```

Then, just use it like `params[:token]` each time. Maybe you can use a shorter variable name for `params` like `p`.

Comment: eh? it works. what the magic did you use? I need some explanation, please

Comment: .-(params.keys) <- this code is what I want to know. Is it even ruby syntax?

Comment: `params.keys` is the list of keys in the hash. When you subtract that from the `[:token, ...]`, then whatever that was not in the `param` as a key will remain. You want this to be `empty?`. Next, you just iterate over `params`, and apply `strip!` to each value of it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that metaprogramming or patterns are necessary in this case, just common sense:

```
[:token, :email, :phone_number, :iso_code].each do |k|
  raise InvalidParameterException if params[k].nil?    
  params[k] = params[k].strip
end
```

I've never understood the popularity of this anti-pattern:

```
par_1 = params[:par_1]
...
par_n = params[:par_n]
```

Why not use the `params[:par_x]` instead? It's usually more convenient to work with params variables grouped in a hash than have them stored into bunch of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method below :

```
def verify_presence_define_var_and_strip(params, symbol_list)
  symbol_list.each do |s|
    raise InvalidParameterException if params[s].nil?
    define_method s, params[s].strip
  end
end
```

With this method, your code could be replace by :

```
verify_presence_define_var_and_strip(params, [:token, :email, :phone_number, :iso_code])
```

Notice that it will define method and not just set a local variable but you should have the same result if you do not already have a method with this name in your class.

You may prefer to use the `instance_variable_set` method but you will have to preceed the variable name by an `@`.

[UPDATE]

If you really want to define local variable and not method / instance variable, I do not know other solution than using eval :

```
eval "#{s} = #{params[:s].strip}"
```

But as you will find if you search about `eval`, it is considered as **bad practice**, moreover in this case where you will evaluate values from URL / POST parameters !

Comment: cool. Though, instance_variable_set works only in Class?
Isn't it possible create local variable dynamically?

Comment: I have updated my answer as `instance_variable_set` need the variable name to start with an `@`. I will also updated it now for your question too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper method that access the params hash and iterates through the elements and checks for nil and throws the exception itself or returns a value to the calling method that could throw the exception.

You can iterate any hash like so,

```
hash.each do |key,value|
 #example nil check
  if value.nil?
    #do what you want
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to raise on nil in your hash of parameters you could do

```
raise InvalidParameterException if params.values.include? nil
```

If you only want to raise on some specific parameters you would have first to pick the values associated to those keys:

```
required_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3]
raise invalidParameterException if required_keys.map{|k| params[k]}.include? nil
```

EDIT: Cannot answer because of lack of points but one of the answer does not work I believe:

```
[:some_key] - {some_key: nil}.keys   # => []
```

If the parameter hash contains one key initialized with value nil (as a result of a failed parse or invalid user input), Array subtraction does not work.